# Why does curve_fit return much different result than Excel Trendline?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

While working with my dataset I noticed that Excel Trend line fitting gives much different results than curve_fit in python:

Excel exponent trend line gives the following equation y = 0.00002178exp(0.53759216x) with a = 0.00002178 and b = 0.53759216

Python curve_fit (unconstrained) results in a = 0.19807362, b = 0.25736161

When plotted Python solution seems less accurate than Excel

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path)

def func(x, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(x*b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, df['x'].values, df['y'].values)
```

Would really appreciate the help to understand why there is rather big differences between Excel and Python in this case.

Here is link to the dataset 
https://www.4shared.com/office/VQUrwRG0iq/New_Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet.html

Or simply below:
x: 27.7
28.1
25.2
27.6
25.7
27.0
25.1
25.5
30.7
27.4
23.6
28.8
28.5
20.3
16.6
22.4
35.2
30.1
28.0
26.3
21.8
23.3
22.1
21.6
22.4
21.5
29.4
35.7
33.5
25.5
29.8
19.5
21.6
22.5
23.5
32.3
29.6
22.4
22.1
21.7
21.3
25.5
25.3
31.3
34.7
35.9
33.4
23.8
21.9
20.1
21.8

y: 950
1050
110
75
28
35
22
14
400
80
38
315
610
0.6
0.2
9.8
630
330
280
65
2.7
9.6
2.3
2.7
1.7
1.7
280
490
265
19
120
1
1.3
2.2
4.5
195
230
1.3
1.1
1
2.1
6
39
2170
1230
4150
2340
4.5
1.4
0.2
0.7

Comment: Can you compute the RMS error for both cases?

Comment: Can you post your data set into your question? I cannot use the 4shared link. I recommend using `df.to_dict()`, if the data aren't too large.

Comment: Ok, I added x and y values to the question (space delimited)

Comment: For the Python fit, I have RMSE =  532.1. Would you please post the RMSE value from the Excel fit?

Answer (score 0):

The data is extremely scattered. As a consequence the result of regression will be very different if the criteria of fitting is not the same.

If we look for the least mean square relative error we find the Excel results. Probably the fitted equation is

ln(y)=ln(a)+bx

RMS relative error = 1.11 ; RMS absolute error = 348

If we look for the least mean square absolute error we find the Python result. Probably the fitted equation is

y=a.exp(bx)

RMS relative error = 18.5 ; RMS absolute error = 280

On graphical representation, subjectively the mean relative error appears better than the absolute error.

If you want obtain with Python something close to Excel, you should specify the criteria of fitting as Relative Error instead of Absolute Error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to specify the criteria of fiting in curve_fit ? Couldn't find in the manual ...

P.S. I voted for your answer but my rating is below 15 and it doesn't change for public...

Comment: I am not specialist of Python. The best should be to specify the criteria for fitting that you want. Ask specialists. If you want to optimize the relative errors, an other way (not really equivalent, but roughly acceptable) should be to fit the equation ln(y)=A+bx instead of y=a.exp(bx) with the usual criteria of absolute errors which means absolute errors on ln(y). The linear regression gives A and b. Then compute a=exp(A).